# no padding on localhost but on webserver?

Tags: html, css, styles, padding

I just have a short question to something that happens at the moment. Am I right that the css settings must be the same as on localhost within one browser when uploading it to a webserver?

i made a screenshot to show what i mean:

here it is whats like on the webserver:

[image: web]

and here what it is on localhost:

[image: local]

i will upload a css file on a webserver and when i will have a look at my localhost page to have a preview i will see it that way. it´s exactly the same file and also the same browser (safari, chrome, firefox). by calling the webservers page there is added a padding to input fields what is exactly in the css:

```
input[type="text"],[type="password"] {
    color: #ccc;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 170px;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    pading-right:5px;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    outline:none;
}
```

and when looking at it on the localhost there isn´t any padding? i use a reset css file but dont think that this causes this phaenomenon. so how is that possible?

only difference i would like to mention is that on localhost th whole body is extended downwards because of the error_reporting of php and the notice messages.

doctype is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

thanks.

Comment: Save the HTML output on both servers and use a diff tool to see if anything is different -- there shouldn't be.

Comment: are you using a reset on both localhost **and** your webserver, or just one of them?

Comment: hello, thanks. what is a diff tool? can you tell me one?

Comment: sure, i use them on both sides.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but did you refresh the browsers cache when viewing the page? http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/cache I've seen browsers do crazy stuff sometimes.

Comment: yes, i already did it before but nothing changed.

Comment: Diff the styles here http://www.quickdiff.com

Comment: okay, thanks. the only difference is the error_reporting notice. hmm.. maybe i should try to set it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in padding-right `pading-right:5px;`

Plus the code you are using is fine, but some time it may happen that some pseudo will not work so better use directly while defining in CSS. like this..

```
    input[type="text"],input[type="password"] {
    color: #ccc;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 170px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding:3px 5px;   
    outline:none;
}
```

Try replacing with this code and reply if not wokring :)